# Mybatis hybrid configuration system

Tags: mybatis

I am writing a CLI app with Mybatis.  In my app, when i go to different menus, it prompts for the user and password for the particular database that menu goes against.

I want to use Guice and Mybatis to handle all this but i have a slight problem.  I want to use the XML config file to handle the mybatis config per database, but the user and pass from each connection has to come from the UI.  So basically, i want to load mybatis xml file for a particular connection, then insert the credentials for the particular connection the user typed in, then bind those to the guice injector for that set of menus.

I can do it in java with a property object pretty easy, but i can't figure out how to do it with loading the XML first, then augmenting it with certain settings before loading.

Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [mybatis guice](http://mybatis.github.io/guice/index.html) this can be done by providing your dataSourceProvider for MyBatisModule like this:

```
Class<? extends Provider<DataSource>> dataSourceProviderType = YourDataSourceProvider.class;

Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
    new MyBatisModule() {

        @Override
        protected void initialize() {
            bindDataSourceProviderType(dataSourceProviderType);
            // other initialization ...
        }

    },
    // other modules
);
```

`YourDataSourceProvider` should be able to create `DataSource` using credentials gotten from UI.

In this case you still can use xml mappers for mybatis.